How to connect a bone loop while rigging
I'm trying to rig a plane that finishes in a loop.

I've already assign dependencies to simulate the tale's mouvement :

But I'm not finding the way to connect the bones that close the loop in order to separate the head mouvement from the tale :

For example: A mouvement dependency problem. I would like to be able to compress the head regardless of tale position, taking in account that the vertices indicated must be joined together:

I've tried parenting them, but it ends in strange formations or with the rest of the bones detached.
Is there a simple solution to achieve independence movements between the head and the tale?
[Updated]
Movement Storyboard :

Project blend file :


Hello could you please explain what object or animal you are trying to animate? what movement it is supposed to do? etc

It is a piece of paper that has a head and a tail. Both parts will have mostly movements on a single axis.

It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

could you please show a storyboard with the movement that your paper is supposed to do? maybe we can propose another solution or rigging?

Thank you for your advice, I've just updated the post with a link to the blend file

Just added a movement storyboard

How does the head need to deform? It’s impossible to give a bone two parents, or to connect bones in a loop, but I’m sure there’s some way to do what you need. Possibly a lattice deform?

Are you sure you could not do it with another kind of rigging, like maybe a curve with hooks?

If you need to be able to compress the head, you could create 2 chains of bones with an IK constraint at their end:

Bones 2, 3 and 4 are parented to bone 1:

